# iOS4 MKMapKit - map not zooming in when more than one pin

Tags: ios4, mkmapview

Sure this is something simple as I'm just starting with the maps.  I already have a map showing one location, but when I've added a second anotation the map stays zoomed all the way out rather than going to my locations.  The pins are there when I zoom in, so I know that bit's working.

Code snippets:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
...
...

// Set coordinates for our position
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = [self.lat doubleValue];
location.longitude = [self.lon doubleValue];

// Add the annotation to our map view
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] 
                                    initWithTitle:self.placename                                        
                                    andSubtitle:self.subtitle
                                    andCoordinate:location];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
[newAnnotation release];

// Set coordinates for our second position
CLLocationCoordinate2D amenitylocation;
amenitylocation.latitude = self.latitude;
amenitylocation.longitude = self.longitude;

// Add the annotation to our map view
MapViewAnnotation *amenityAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] 
                                    initWithTitle:self.callouttitle                                        
                                    andSubtitle:self.calloutsubtitle
                                    andCoordinate:amenitylocation];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:amenityAnnotation];
[amenityAnnotation release];

[super viewDidLoad];

}



#pragma mark - MKMapView Delegates

// When a map annotation point is added, zoom to it (1500 range)
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 1500, 1500);
[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
[mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
if(mapView.userLocation==annotation)
{
    return nil;
}

NSString *identifier = @"IDENTIFIER";

MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

if(annotationView==nil)
{
    annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];
    annotationView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    annotationView.canShowCallout=YES;
}

return annotationView;
}
```

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Also, am I right in thinking I'll have to make custom callouts if I want more than one to appear on the map at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found the answer - I didn't have the MKMapView delegate linked to File's Owner in IB, although I do have  in my header file.  Linked that up and it's working.